# Wp-cli-ssh global installation problem

Tags: wp-cli

Global installation of [wp-cli-ssh](https://github.com/xwp/wp-cli-ssh) returns following error:

```
$ composer global require x-team/wp-cli-ssh dev-master
Changed current directory to /Users/name/.composer

./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  **Problem 1
    - The requested package xwp/wp-cli-ssh could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.**

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see **https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion** for more details.  

Read **https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md** for further common problems
```

The `composer.json` file looks like the following:

```
{
   "minimum-stability":"dev",
   "require":{

   },
   "config":{
      "bin-dir":"bin",
      "vendor-dir":"vendor"
   },
   "repositories":{
      "wp-cli":{
         "type":"composer",
         "url":"http://wp-cli.org/package-index/ "
      }
   }
}
```

Looking forward for a guidance on What I am missing in this.

Comment: Which version of Composer are you running? It appears that it's not trying to find package on GitHub. Secondly, requiring it globally `composer global` won't add it to the local `composer.json` file.

Comment: Please note that the package index for `wp-cli` is no longer available https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/1598 so you should remove it from the `repositories` list.

Comment: Hello, I am using 

$ composer --version
Composer version 1.0-dev (dc5f8cfbaabb571c54cd4d21091a5c45bd9eaa14) 2015-12-03 10:43:39

Which repository would be better to add on composer.json

I tried adding https://github.com/xwp/wp-cli-ssh/archive/master.zip as a repository, but then it returned the error 


**Problem 1
    - The requested package xwp/wp-cli-ssh could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.**